# How to delay in fragment and cancel in onPause

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I just want to delay a task in a fragment and if the app goes to the background while the delay is running the scope should never resume when the app comes to the foreground:
With following 2 approaches both will execute once the app comes back again, but I want that this never returns once the app was in the background. How to achieve that?

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
  lifecycle.whenResumed {
    Timber.d("before delay 1")
    delay(15000)
    Timber.d("after delay 1")
  }
}
lifecycleScope.launch {
  viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
    Timber.d("before delay 2")
    delay(15000)
    Timber.d("after delay 2")
  }
}
```

kotlinx.coroutines.delay()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Job launched by lifecycleScope will not be canceled until lifecycle destroy
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleCoroutineScope

If you need to run it once you have to write something like this

```
private var delayedJob: Job? = null

override fun onResume() {
    if(delayedJob == null) {
        delayedJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            Timber.d("before delay")
            delay(15000) 
            Timber.d("after delay")
        }
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    delayedJob?.cancel()
}
```